# How to permanently disable the right pane and enable the left panel in Adobe Acrobat Reader 15?

Tags: adobe-reader

How do i hide the useless “comment” pane and instead permanently show the left-hand buttons (thumbnails, etc) in Adobe Reader 15, like i could in version 11?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove or prevent sidebar from opening by default on Adobe Reader](https://superuser.com/questions/902758/remove-or-prevent-sidebar-from-opening-by-default-on-adobe-reader)

Answer (score -1):

You can click the arrow/triangle located at the middle of the left and right panes to show or hide them, respectively, as shown in your picture (replicated below).

[image]