# Hide tools pane and show page thumbnails by default

Tags: adobe-reader

I've recently upgraded to Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (version 2015.007.20033)

Is it possible to hide tools pane and show page thumbnails / navigation pane by default?

Although it's easy to do them, it's two extra clicks EACH time I open a pdf.

[image]

(This question has been [asked](https://superuser.com/questions/898742/how-to-permanently-disable-the-right-pane-and-enable-the-left-panel-in-adobe-acr) already, but it doesn't have a good answer.)

Comment: It should be possible to do from the settings, but it has been a long time ago and I currently use Foxit Reader instead of Adobe Reader because it works so much nicer.

Comment: I've already checked settings, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not surprised, the name of the setting is really weird. I found it through a google search back then, but I can't test it as I don't use the software anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy answer to the first part of your question, answered [here](https://superuser.com/a/1173789): You can keep the tool pane closed as follows:

1. Launch Acrobat Reader
2. Close the tool pane
3. Edit>Preferences, Documents section
4. Check the box, "Remember current state of the Tools Pane"

This works for me with Acrobat Reader 2023 on Windows 10.